# What is the name of this metalwork for decorating furniture?

Tags: furniture

I'd like to decorate a cabinet with metalwork, but I can't search for this item of metalwork because I have no idea what it's called.

It looks like a brass boob and nipple (sorry, but it does) and is found on a lot of Indian furniture:

[image]

Does anyone know what it's called?

Do you know where I might source such an item?

Comment: These look a little like the surrounds for some old doorbells, called escutcheons, that might give you a starting point for looking for something similar. Are these a historical feature of Indian furniture or still in use today?

Comment: @Graphus escutcheons didn't lead me to any similar images, but I really appreciate the help!  I think they could be a historical feature. A lot of India furniture is recycled from old, magnificently-carved doors. It may be something that I cannot buy new and have to buy recycled. I don't mind that. I'm going for the rustic look. If only I knew what to search for!  Thanks!

Comment: @Graphus YES! I searched on antique twist doorbells and found some escutcheons  that would work beautifully for my cabinets!!  You have indeed pointed me in the right direction!  Thank you for your time, I'm so grateful.

Comment: Welcome, glad it was of some help.

Comment: @AndreiRînea I have a star chest covered in them but we call it 'The booby chest'. :)